# Using separate mutexs for pop and push operatin of std::queue instead of one

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, locking

Suppose there are one producer and multiple consumer and they use a `std::queue`, in order to protect the data in `std::queue`, a mutex must be used when accessing this `std::queue`.

But what about using two separate locks? One for `pop` and one for `push`? I think it might be faster using two separate locks.

I looked at the STL source code. The `std::queue` is implemented by `std::deque` by default. `pop_front()` and `push_back()` use two separate iterators to access the data, one for the first element, and one for the last element.

```
void push_front(const value_type& __x){
    if (this->_M_impl._M_start._M_cur != this->_M_impl._M_start._M_first){
        this->_M_impl.construct(this->_M_impl._M_start._M_ur - 1, __x);
    } else {
        _M_push_front_aux(__x);
    }
}

void push_back(){
    if (this->_M_impl._M_finish._M_cur != this->_M_impl._M_finish._M_first){
        this->_M_impl.construct(this->_M_impl._M_finish._M_ur - 1, __x);
    } else {
        _M_pop_back_aux();
    }
}
```

So, when one thread is `pop`ing the queue, another thread cuts in and tries to `push_back`. Because these two operations use different iterators which points to the two different end point of `deque`, so it seems that these two operations will all be ok?

Comment: Separate mutexes make no sense, for protection from race conditions.

Comment: No, both `push` and `pop` cause changes to internal data of the deque, like `size`.

Comment: Sounds like a deadlock generator to me:(

Comment: @MartinJames Some friend asked me this question, and I didn't figure it out. Thank you for your comments!

Comment: @BoPersson Oh, I got it. I thought it was just adding/removing elements... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pop_front` and `push_back` may be accessing different iterators internally, but that's the whole sense of abstraction: You cannot be sure of that, and moreover aren't allowed to rely on it.

And, as already pointed out in the comments, there's also `size`, which is since C++11 required to perform in `O(1)`. To hold that requirement, both `push_back` and `pop_front` need to mutate some internal storage if the size, which is where you have a race condition for sure.

Then think of what happens when your queue gets empty ...

In short: Don't do that. To use a `std::queue` in a concurrent setting, you need one mutex to protect it.

As an alternative you should look into lock-free data structures.

Comment: Some friend asked me this question, and I didn't figure it out. Thank you for your answer!